# how to use custom hook in react hook form submit function?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I am working on the next 13 and I have used the `react hook form`. Also, I have created one custom hook inside the hook folder `src/hooks/use-api.ts` for global API functions like useGet, usePost, etc..

The issue is I have set the hook function usePost inside the submit form method but when I submit it returns the error `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component`

**app/login/page.tsx**

```js
"use client";
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import InputText from "../../components/InputText.js";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import * as yup from "yup";
import { noti } from "../../utils/helper.js"; 
import usePost from "../../hooks/use-api";

const schema = yup.object({
  email: yup
    .string()
    .required("Please enter email")
    .matches(/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/, "Please enter valid email"),
  password: yup.string().required("Please enter password"),
});
const Login = () => {
  //const navigate = useNavigate();

  const {
    control,
    setValue,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      email: "",
      password: "",
    },
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });

  //Submit form
  const onSubmit = (data: object) => {
    let params = {
      email: "",
      password: "",
    };
    usePost("user", params)
      .then(({ data }) => {
        console.log("data", data);
      })
      .catch((error: any) => {
        noti("error", error);
      });
  }; 
  // JSX code for login form
  const renderForm = (
    <>
      <form className="space-y-4 md:space-y-6" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="email" className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
            Your email
          </label>
          <InputText
            label={"Email"}
            name="email"
            control={control}
            helperText={errors.email?.message}
            onChange={(e: { target: { value: string } }) => setValue("email", e.target.value)}
            class="w-4 h-4 border border-gray-300 rounded bg-gray-50 focus:ring-3 focus:ring-primary-300 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:focus:ring-primary-600 dark:ring-offset-gray-800"
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="password" className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
            Password
          </label>
          <InputText
            label={"Password"}
            name="password"
            control={control}
            helperText={errors.password?.message}
            onChange={(e: { target: { value: string } }) => setValue("password", e.target.value)}
            class="w-4 h-4 border border-gray-300 rounded bg-gray-50 focus:ring-3 focus:ring-primary-300 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:focus:ring-primary-600 dark:ring-offset-gray-800"
          />
        </div>
        <button
          type="submit"
          className="bg-sky-700 w-full text-white hover:bg-sky-900 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center  dark:hover:bg-sky-900 dark:focus:ring-sky-800"
        >
          Sign in
        </button>
        <p className="text-sm font-light text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-700">
          Don’t have an account yet?{" "}
          <a href="#" className="font-medium text-primary-600 hover:underline dark:text-primary-500">
            Sign up
          </a>
        </p>
      </form>
    </>
  );

  return (
    <section className="bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-900">
      <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center px-6 py-8 mx-auto md:h-screen lg:py-0">
        <a href="#" className="flex items-center mb-6 text-2xl font-semibold text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
          Login
        </a>
        <div className="w-full bg-white rounded-lg shadow dark:border md:mt-0 sm:max-w-md xl:p-0 dark:bg-white-800 dark:border-gray-700">
          <div className="p-6 space-y-4 md:space-y-6 sm:p-8">
            <h1 className="text-xl font-bold leading-tight tracking-tight text-gray-800 md:text-2xl dark:text-gray text-center">
              Sign in to your account
            </h1>
            {renderForm}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

**src/hooks/use-api.ts**

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import { useState, useEffect, SetStateAction } from 'react';
const config = {
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "kishan": "patel",
  }
};
export default function useGet(endpoint: string) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Make an API request to get the data.
    let aa = process.env.API_BASE
    axios.get("http://localhost:4100/V1/" + endpoint, config).then((response: { data: any; }) => {
      setData(response.data);
    });
  }, [endpoint]);

  return data;
}

export function usePost(endpoint: string, params: any) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Make an API for POST request.
    axios.post("http://localhost:4100/V1/" + endpoint, params).then((response: { data: any; }) => {
      setData(response.data);
    });
  }, [endpoint]);

  return data;
}
```

if I move the usePost function above the submit then the API call works but I need to call API after the form is submitted.

Comment: You may refer to the following web page:
https://dev.to/darkmavis1980/fetching-data-with-react-hooks-and-axios-114h

Comment: Thanks for your quick revert but I want to use the global API function like everytime use axios.post instead of postAPI or usePost something. Can you please help me how can I do this?

Comment: Also it will working fine with get result but I want to use same hook after submit function

Comment: You can refer to the web page below:
https://dev.to/hey_yogini/useaxios-a-simple-custom-hook-for-calling-apis-using-axios-2dkj

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `hooks` inside a function. There are two [`rules`](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions) keep in mind before creating custom hook:

```
Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions. Instead, you can:
✅ Call Hooks from React function components.
✅ Call Hooks from custom Hooks
```

So better to call hook in the parent of the component and expose a function from hook which you can use to call API(If you want to use hook).

Else, better to create a function instead of a hook which can be used anywhere in your app even in custom hook.

**`BETTER SOLUTION`**

You can create a class `RestClient` as below, whole only responsibility will be to hit API and error handling also.

```
class RestClient {
    // ...
    static post(endpoint, params) {
        try {
            const data = axios.post("http://localhost:4100/V1/" + endpoint, params)
            return data;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
        
    });
}
// ...
}
```

and use it as:

```
// CREATE STATE IF YOU NEED DATA
const [data, setData] = useState();

// ...
//Submit form
const onSubmit = (data: object) => {
    let params = {
        email: "",
        password: "",
    };
    RestClient.post("endpoint", params)
        .then(res => setData(res))
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
};
```

Comment: Thanks @DecPk for youe answer. So can I use a simple file and use this as a global API function. and if I want to use the hook then can you provide an example please so I can get better idea with my initial next start

Comment: @KishanBhensadadiya I've added a code snippet. You can get an idea

Comment: Thanks, dude! I have used the class for the global API function and seems working fine.